# Is there a way to load only a few items from a large list of objects and populate into a UICollectionView

Tags: ios, swift, list, uicollectionview, prefetch

I have a List containing 100 objects, but i want to load only the first 10 and populate it into my `UICollectionView`  and when i scroll down i can then populate the remaining objects into the list.

This must be performed in a  `UICollectioView` and Swift 4 and above

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Load More data on Scroll Demand on CollectionView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41905253/load-more-data-on-scroll-demand-on-collectionview)

Comment: Is there a specific reason you need to do this? UICollectionView will (in short) only load visible cells.

Comment: are the large list of object being fetched from api?

Comment: @Alastar No the large list of data has already been fetched from the API.

Comment: can't you use pagination as parameter in that api?

Comment: @Alastar . i dont have any controller over the API

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you already have the array present, you can split it into pages and then display the pages you need:

```
let entries = Array(1...100).split(into: 10)
```

...using this extension:

```
extension Array {
    func split(into size: Int) -> [[Element]] {
        return stride(from: 0, to: count, by: size).map {
            Array(self[$0..<Swift.min($0 + size, count)])
        }
    }
}
```

Then, you could display the first array as the first page, second as second, and so on.

---

<sup>taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54450953/3397217)</sup>

Comment: after splitting the array to 10 how do i populate the data into the `UICollectionView` and prevent it from loading only 10 items when the user scrolls up or down

Comment: You have two options here: use the `prefetchItems` or the `willDisplay` methods. For the latter, check out [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48075049/3397217).